# Isolate one sheet from global filter

Tags: filter, powerbi

I am not very experienced on Power BI yet and I am currently facing an issue while working on an existing Sales report.
Basically, I want to isolate a single sheet from an already applied global filter without having to remove it and reapply it independently on each sheet, as it would make it tedious for the user.

After looking at some other posts on StackOverflow I found the 'modify interactions' option in the Format section but couldn't manager to make it isolate either the whole page from the global filters or even the visuals one at a time.

I haven't been able to find an answer to this question, hence why I am not even sure this is possible.
Does anyone know how to do this or if this is even possible ?

Thank you very much !

Comment: This may depend a bit on what is being filtered on the page from the global filters.  You might be able to rewrite measures to ignore them, or you might be stuck if it's a filter on a column that you are displaying in that page.  Could you provide some more details about how the filters are working and what's on the page you want excluded?

Comment: @Mark I believe the page/report filters are applied prior to any `ALL` functions in measures, so you cannot simply rewrite your DAX for this.

Comment: @Marcus from what I've seen in Dax traces, the filters are applied with `TREATAS` statements.  This means they behave like any filter in DAX and can be removed in a measure.  However, this would only be useful if the filter is not on a column that is being displayed in the report and it is just impacting calculations.

Comment: @Mark I suppose it would be useful if you demonstrate this.

Answer (score 1):

If you have measures that need to ignore the filters, you can rewrite the measures on that page to ignore them.  Here is an example:

Teams data:
[image]

I added a filter for all pages where the channel is `Development - PowerBI`.  The channel count in the card is `1`

[image]

Add another measure to the report which ignores this filter:

```
Active channels (all) =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Teams usage summary'[Active channels] ),
    REMOVEFILTERS ( 'Teams usage summary'[Team name] )
)
```

This card shows `41`, the total count of all channels for all teams:
[image]

Please note that this will not work if I have `team name` in the report - it will show only the filtered team, but the total count of all channels, which is not what we want in this case. Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Very useful, but as you say, with a major caveat. I imagine most use cases that want to lift a report-wide filter want to display what is elsewhere filtered. Anyhow, thanks for demonstrating this!

Comment: @Marcus Yeh, it would fit certain use cases -- like if you filtered all pages to show a rolling 52 week period but one page needed to show 3 years of history.  Totally depends on the scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, excluding a page from the global filters is not possible.